# Is this the stochastic differential of the given process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let the process $$X_t:=\cos(B_{1,t}B_{2,t}),$$ where $(B_1, B_2)$ is a bi-dimensional correlated Brownian motion, be given. Is the following the correct Ito representation of its stochastic differential?
$$dX_t = \\-\frac12 \left\{\rho^{1,1}B_{2,t}^2\cos{(B_{1,t}B_{2,t})} + \rho^{2,2}B_{1,t}^2\cos{(B_{1,t}B_{2,t})} \\+ \rho^{2,1}[\sin{(B_{1,t}B_{2,t})} + B_{1,t}B_{2,t}\cos{(B_{1,t}B_{2,t})}]\right\}dt \\- B_{2,t}\sin{(B_{1,t}B_{2,t})}dB_{1,t}-B_{1,t}\sin{(B_{1,t}B_{2,t})}dB_{2,t}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_t:=B_{1,t}B_{2,t}$, so that $X_t=\cos(Y_t)$ and
$$
dX_t=-\sin(Y_t)dY_t -{1\over 2}\cos(Y_t)d\langle Y\rangle_t.
$$
To make this more explicit, use
$$
dY_t=B_{1,t} dB_{2,t}+B_{2,t} dB_{1,t}+\rho^{2,1} dt
$$
(if I guess correctly at what you mean by $\rho^{2,1}$), and
$$
d\langle Y\rangle_t = B_{1,t}^2\rho^{2,2} dt +B_{2,t}^2\rho^{1,1} dt + 2B_{1,t}B_{2,t}\rho^{2,1} dt.
$$
It looks to me like your formula is correct except your $-{1\over 2}\rho^{2,1}\sin(B_{1,t}B_{2,t}) dt$ term shouldn't have a ${1\over 2}$.